# C# ASP.NET: can't convert datetime to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, cultureinfo, iformatprovider

I want to convert a `datetime` to string.

But result now is returned as `04 August, 0016` which is not what I need.

I want result to be `04 August, 2016`.

C# code:

```
DataTable dtGroupCurr = new DataTable();
dtGroupCurr = sourceGroupCurr.Tables[0];

var groupedCurr = (from dt2 in dtGroupCurr.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
         S_DATE = dt2.Field<DateTime>("S_DATE"),
         BANK_CODE = dt2.Field<string>("BANK_CODE"),
         BANK_NAME = dt2.Field<string>("BANK_NAME")
    }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.S_DATE);

foreach (var s in groupedCurr)
{
     string rDate = s.S_DATE.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
     IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
     DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(rDate, culture);
     string sDate = date.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Looks good, take a look : https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPFBrk

Comment: I agree with @un-lucky, it looks fine. Expanded version: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPFBrk .What does the end result in `rDate` look like and is `s.S_Date` a "pure" date time or does it do something else?

Comment: What value had s.S_DATE ? before .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

Comment: @Mate I answer on topic. look code.

Comment: great. I can't understand the "extra" parse step. Did you try s.S_DATE.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US", true));  .  if that doesn't work. Please, add s.S_DATE.ToString() output.

Comment: or maybe try changing  s.S_DATE.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")  >>  s.S_DATE.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)  '/' - the date separator. It will be replaced according current culture

Comment: And we sill don't have clear answer as to the value of `S_Date` because as we have demonstraded the basic code works, so the issue could be in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 string sDate = s.S_DATE.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
```

Or

```
string rDate = s.S_DATE.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // To avoid override 
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(rDate, culture);
string sDate = date.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified
>   culture.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method and specify the format like below:

```
string rDate = s.S_DATE.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(rDate, "yyyy/MM/dd", culture);
string sDate = date.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Date or **DateTime.ToShortDateString();**
Or
**Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");**